Pressurisation in the Apollo Lunar Module?
After the Apollo 1 fire, the Command Module atmosphere at launch was 15psi of 60:40 nitrogen:oxygen, which was allowed to vent down to 5psi during the ascent, and then slowly changed over to 5psi oxygen.
How was the LM cabin atmosphere managed during ascent? Having only 5psi of oxygen in it at take-off seems structurally perilous, given its fragility and the higher external pressure, but venting down to 5psi is something else to go wrong, posing a risk of it venting down to vaccum.
